# Poor RemoteFX Performance

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have Hyper-V running on an DELL Optiplex 9020MT Core i7 3.8GHz with 32GB RAM on Windows Server 2012 R2.

For testing purposes I enabled RemoteFX on the Intel HD 4600 graphics chip built in to the CPU.

I then added the RemoteFX adapter in an 8.1 Enterprise guest, and video performance is really bad.

A Windows 7 guest without any RemoteFX adapter with my Wyse RDP client works amazing it is really smooth.

Anything I have done wrong or should check? Or is ut simply a case of the Intel 4600 HD graphics being slower than emulated?

Comment: You mean except using a totally crappy hardware? HD 4600 intel is not powerfull enough to even come close to be a RemoteFx capable hardware.

Comment: Yup agree suspected as such just needed confirmation - any recommendations for GPU for a test lab where i will be running up to 3 clients remotely? Also what about if wanted to scale this out with proper server grade hardware for up to 50 users?

Comment: Nt really, BUT: Take a REAL card. Something that has memory. AMD cards work well, and even lower end cards have some GC dedicated memory. 50 users WILL be challenging requiring more a gamer motherboard than a typical server one - because you likely need to load 4-6 graphics cards.

Comment: have a look at [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2013/11/05/gpu-requirements-for-remotefx-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx) about reccomended requirements. A mid-level graphics card is the Quadro K6000 which is currently listed on Google results for a mere £4k. You may fine desktop cards may work slightly better than intergrated chips however.

Comment: Great thanks for the comments really useful. Not sure why the down vote i think its a valid question (even mentioning suspect HD 4600!), feel free to drop an answer and will accept

Comment: @tomtom were you to answer this I would have upvoted you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel 4600 HD graphics chip is extremely underpowered for this application.

You need a graphics card specifically designed for remote desktop workloads that can render multiple desktops at once if you are using RemoteFX.  The nVidia GRID and ATI FirePro are such cards.

Comment: Per http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931/126699

Comment: Would a thin client such as a Wyse D10DP make any difference in video rendering?

Comment: No, it has almost nothing to do with the client in this case.  remotefx is a mechanism for the VMs in a host to (more or less) directly use the host's GPU.  The thin client will be rendering the already-rasterized display as usual.